# boost::asio::async_read doesn't call the handler and keeps receiving

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

boost::asio::async_read doesn't call the handler and keeps receiving, am trying to receive some buffers that I don't know it's length , but max is 1024

```
#include "AsyncConnection.h"


AsyncConnection::AsyncConnection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket(io_service)
{
}


AsyncConnection::~AsyncConnection()
{
}

AsyncConnection::Pointer AsyncConnection::Create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service){
    return Pointer(new AsyncConnection(io_service));
}

boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& AsyncConnection::GetSocket(){
    return socket;
}

void AsyncConnection::BeginReceive(){

    boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer, 1024),
        boost::bind(&AsyncConnection::EndReceive, shared_from_this(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void AsyncConnection::EndReceive(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred){
    if (!error){

    }
    else{
        std::cout << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

it never calls the `EndReceive` , my guess is it's keeping receiving until the buffer is full?! how to fix that tho!

Comment: Are you calling `io_service.run();` or `io_service.run_one();` correctly ?

Comment: `io_service.run();` yeah!

Comment: If you have not already, then it may be worth familiarizing oneself with the [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html) documentation.  The `async_read()` [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload2.html) indicates how to specify completion conditions.

Comment: if I used `boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1)` would be fine!?

Comment: If you don't know the message size anyway, you'd be better off using `async_read_some`.